# App Clip invoking from NFC Tag - only one NDEF record allowed?

Tags: ios, nfc, ndef, apple-appclips

Good day everyone,

We have an iOS app containing App Clip which should appear after scanning an URL from an NFC tag. Now if the tag contains *ONLY* one NDEF URL Record, the App Clip appears.

But if there are more fields (as in our case), while URL record being still the first. App Clip is not started, iOS tries to open URL in safari.

Any hands-on experience on this? Apple doc is silent on this.